# How to resolve windows container IP from DNS on Windows 10 using Docker for Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, dns, docker-for-windows, windows-container

How, from a Windows 10 host, can I access containers through their hostnames?

For example, if I have two containers

- container-a
- container-b

I want to be able to use this command from the host and have it resolve to the IP address of container-a:

```
ping container-a
```

I'm running the latest stable Docker for Windows on Windows 10 using the Windows Container mode.

I'm using the default "nat" network type, with a subnet of 172.20.16.0/20

From the host machine, the docker NIC details:

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (HNS Internal NIC):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.16.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

and the physical NIC details:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.173(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1:1%5
                                       192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Does the host NIC need to have the docker NIC's IP in it's DNS list?

Comment: You would not be able to do that with default network but you shall be able if you set your container to connect to bridge network and this way they will get IP address through DHCP and register their name with DNS

Comment: Typically in Docker - haven't used Docker for Windows - you map ports in containers to ports on the host.  Docker compose can setup a pseudo DNS like you described between multiple docker containers but not between host and container